# create folder in c# as we do in normal windows

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

We are listing the folders and files of a directory in a mvc view as below:

```
Afolder
Bfolder
Cfolder
Dfolder
test.jp
test2.jpg
.
.
.
testN.jpg

+Create folder
```

This is typically a file explorer. By clicking on any folder the contents of that folder are displayed.

When we click on Create folder button, a folder textbox should appear down the Dfolder with option to rename. Same as how we create folder in windows or in visual studio.

can somebody advise if this can be achieved using C#, mvc and jQuery?

Or advise other alternatives if any?

Comment: AS far as I cant see, if the application pool of your MVC application has modify rights on the root of your intented "file manager", It could be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for response, can u advise how this can be achiveved?

Comment: Explaining it all would take me some time, but here you can find some inspiration : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/176166/Simple-FileManager-width-MVC-and-jsTree